# Does qt have something like find_if from STL?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4.8

Imagine I have a struct like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    foo *fara;
    int id;
} fooToIDWrapper_t;
```

and a `QLinkedList<fooToIDWrapper_t *> FooWrapper;` like that,

Now I want to get the iterator where the lists `fooToIDWrapper_t`-node matches a specfic id.

with STL's `std:find_if()` I could achieve this, by doing (just example code to demonstrate, not checked for compilability):

```
vector<fooToIDWrapper_t> bar;

auto pred = [ID](const fooToIDWrapper& item) {
    return item.id == ID;
};

std::find_if(std::begin(bar), std::end(bar), pred) != std::end(bar);
```

Does there an similiar algorithm exist in qt? and if not so, as I assume, what way I could achieve this in qt?

Comment: Does Qt not support the standard library?

Comment: @NathanOliver: I should add, that I'm relying on an iterator. And have to admit having no idea how to mix this.

Comment: No, it doesn't have: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtalgorithms.html  (see: Porting guidelines).

Comment: `std::find_if` uses iterators.  You should be able to drop this code in and change `bar` to whatever the linked list is named and it should work.

Comment: That would be great. I'll have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `QLinkedList` in a `find_if`! That's exactally why `QLinkedList` provides [`cbegin`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlinkedlist.html#cbegin) and [`cend`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlinkedlist.html#cend):

```
find_if(cbegin(bar), cend(bar), [ID](const fooToIDWrapper& item) { return item.id == ID;} ) != cend(bar)
```

Also consider: [`any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) which seems like it would make more sense given that you're just going to compare the resulting iterator to `cend(bar)`:

```
any_of(cbegin(bar), cend(bar), [ID](const fooToIDWrapper& item) { return item.id == ID;})
```

**EDIT:**

You still want to use `const` iterators since you are not trying to modify the container. You'll just need to use [`constBegin`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlinkedlist.html#constBegin) and [`constEnd`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlinkedlist.html#constEnd) before Qt5. So you could do this:

```
any_of(bar.constBegin(), bar.constEnd(), [ID](const fooToIDWrapper& item) { return item.id == ID;})
```

If you feel the incessant need to use [the `iterator` libraries' accesors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38101301/2642059) with Qt4 you wouldn't be able to use `const` iterators:

```
any_of(begin(bar), end(bar), [ID](const fooToIDWrapper& item) { return item.id == ID;})
```

Comment: this would be a great solution! But sadly I'm limited to qt 4.8

Comment: @Zaibis Fear not, Qt4 also provided `const` iterators, the accessor functions just had nonstandard names. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to not use `std::find_if` in this case. `STL` algorithms are crossplatform and compatible with `Qt` containers. There is no similar algorithm in `QtAlgorithm` library

```
QLinkedList<fooToIDWrapper_t *> bar;

auto pred = [ID](const fooToIDWrapper& item) {
    return item.id == ID;
};

std::find_if(bar.begin(), bar.end(), pred) != std::end(bar);
```