# Can I use the iterator Libraries' Access Functions on Nonstandard Containers?

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, c++14, c++17

The `iterator` library has been introducing a lot of [access functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator#Range_access) over the course of C++11, C++14, and C++17:

- `begin`/`end`
- `cbegin`/`cend`
- `crbegin`/`crend`
- `data`
- `empty`
- `rbegin`/`rend`
- `size`

Can I use these on any container, even nonstandard containers (provided they supply an accessible corresponding method?) For example given a [`QVector`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html) `foo` can I do this:

```
const auto bar = begin(foo);
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to?  All they do is call the appropriate member function.

Comment: You can if: (a) your class provides corresponding member functions; or (b) you provide overloads specific to your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declarations for `std::begin` are as follow (from §24.7):

```
template <class C> auto begin(C& c) -> decltype(c.begin());
template <class C> auto begin(const C& c) -> decltype(c.begin());
```

So these functions will be defined for any class `C` such that `c.begin()` is "valid" (does exist). The standard also guarantees that these will:

> *Returns:* `c.begin()`.

So **yes** you can use `begin(c)` on any container of type `C` as long as either:

- The member function `C::begin()` is provided.
- There exist a `begin(C const&)` or `begin(C &)` function.

The standalone `begin` function should not be in the `std::` namespace but rather in the same namespace as your class `C` so name-lookup can find it.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, your question seem to be: if the container provides a member function `begin`, can I then call it as a free function? The answer to your question is yes, because a templated free function begin is provided by the standard, that simply tries to call the member function begin; from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin: "Returns an iterator to the beginning of the given container c or array array. These templates rely on `C::begin()` having a reasonable implementation.".